# Square's Picasso Retry Mechanism in Android

Tags: android, picasso

Does Picasso have a retry mechanism when failed to download images from web ?

I've noticed at their website that they mentioned a 3 times retry until error placeholder is shown.

I currently do not use placeholder (not for error and not while waiting for the image to download).

Is there a way to configure that myself when building Picasso object ?

I'm using the Picasso.with(...).load(...).into(...) builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrying is not done by Picasso, but the http client that performs the downloading requests. If you are using default `OkHttpDownloader` your client must be setting retry flag for `OkHttpClient`, i.e `okHttpClient.setRetryOnConnectionFailure(true)`.

Alternatively, use `Interceptor` and count the number of retries until the request is executed successfully.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the OKhttp protocol with Picasso. Is there a way to config a fixed number of retry count with this function above ?

Comment: Picasso suggestion on this "Set this to false to avoid retrying requests when doing so is destructive. In this case the calling application should do its own recovery of connectivity failures."

Comment: But how do you get the `okHttpClient` object?

Answer (score 3):

the easiest way is to add an `interceptor` to your `okhttpclient` and then setup the `singleton` of `picasso` in your application class

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            Response response = chain.proceed(request);
            int tryCount = 0;
            while (!response.isSuccessful() && tryCount < 5) {
                tryCount++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                response = chain.proceed(request);
            }
            return response;
        }
    })
    .build();

Picasso picasso = new Picasso
        .Builder(this)
        .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(okHttpClient))
        .build();

Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);
```

Answer (score 2):

I write a helper function here , hope it is helpful

You may check it out, with MAX_RETRY_TIME.

Add retry process in "interceptors"

[My Gist Helper Class](https://gist.github.com/extralam/cda4ce0d7341b929efd4)

Comment: Per Stack Overflow's policy, please edit code into your answer that is pertinent to this issue.